# Angular UI Router & Security

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement some security in my app using angular ui-router's `resolve` function. I've fashioned a solution based on solution #2 in the 2nd answer to this question: [Angular ui-router: how to prevent access to a state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518181/angular-ui-router-how-to-prevent-access-to-a-state)

It works fine, except that the controller for routes I do not want to allow the user to navigate to is still instantiated. I'm more or less following John Papa's recommendations for Angular, so I have an `activate` function in each controller. I could double check authentication here, but that would require repetitive work be done to each of my controllers. Also, eliminating the use of `$timeout` in the authenticate function from the original answer doesn't seem to have an adverse effect.

Here is how I am setting up a route to handle this:

```
$stateProvider.state('orderqueue', {
                url: "/orderqueue",
                templateUrl: "views/orderqueue.html",
                controller: 'orderQueueController',
                controllerAs: 'orders',
                role: 'Order Admin', 
                resolve: {authenticate: authenticate}
            });
```

and my authenticate function looks like this:

```
function authenticate($q,$state,$timeout, UserService) {
            (new UserService()).$getUser().then(
                function(user) {
                    var role = ($state.current.role) ? $state.current.role :$state.current.name ;

                    // alert(role) ;
                    if (user.userName == 'wmfeltman') {
                        return $q.when()    
                    } else
                    {
                        //  $timeout(function() {
                        // This code runs after the authentication promise has been rejected.
                        // Go to the log-in page
                            $state.go('login')
                        // })
                        // Reject the authentication promise to prevent the state from loading
                        return $q.reject()
                    }
                }
            ) 
        }
```

Is there a way to get resolve to fire before the controller is instantiated? The docs seem to indicate that is how it's supposed to work, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. I see most of the people defines the `controller` in the state configuration itself.

But you should define the controller in the view itself using `ng-controller` like this:

`views/orderqueue.html`

```
<div ng-controller="orderQueueController as orders">
    <!-- your stuff -->
</div>
```

Now, you can remove the `controller` and `controllerAs` from the state configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('`', {
            url: "/orderqueue",
            templateUrl: "views/orderqueue.html",
            role: 'Order Admin', 
            resolve: {authenticate: authenticate}
        });
```

This way, if your authentication is not successful, the `orderqueue` will not load, hence, your `views/orderqueue.html` will not be loaded so the controller will not instantiate (since the controller is  initiated with the HTML view).

Comment: I guess that's simple enough, but not really desirable. I'm actually moving towards a data-driven solution for all of my routes, controllers, templates, etc. and don't really like embedding the controller references in my views. Does the new router in 1.5 function the same? Seems like it might be a good move to go in that direction at this point in time as that will also help with prep for Angular 2.0 migration.

Comment: For the record, though, your suggestion does work as expected.

Comment: Actually, I take my comment back. The controller is still instantiated before resolve is called using this methodology as well.

Comment: Thanks. Since the resolve function is actually injected into the controller, it doesn't seem like resolve is a viable option here. I suppose if a controller method could be called after resolve, then it would be feasible to construct things that way. Since the resolve property is actually a map object it seems like it would be possible to simply have the "activate" code in a second item in the map object, but that won't really fly with asynchronous promises. Reading the doc, it implies that all of this should take place before the controller instantiates, tracing reveals otherwise.