# add access levels to stateprovider by checking if current user has a specific role

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, satellizer

I've implemented satellizer(https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) as my authentication. What I want is something along (https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth)'s method of access levels and role permission, based on this:

I have added a role field to my userSchema on the server side that. How would I implement a system like this to check which role the authenticated user has, and then use that to show/protect certain routes in app.js's stateprovider?
I've been trying to implement this for some time without any progress.

EDIT: 
after checking the link @paul linked this is what I've come to thus far.

```
.state('admin', {
      url: '/admin',
      template: 'Scripts/App/partials/admin.html',
      controller: 'AdminCtrl',
      resolve: {
          security: ['$q', function ($q) {
              if(!isAdmin()) {
                  return $q.reject('Not Authorized');
              }
          }]
      }
  })

function isAdmin($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/isadmin')
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.role = response.data.role;
            console.log($scope.role);
        });
    if ($scope.role == 'admin') {
        console.log($scope.role);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

App.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (error === "Not Authorized") {
        $state.go("notAuthorizedPage");
    }
  });
}]);
```

These are all in app.js, and this is where I'm stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ui-router: how to prevent access to a state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518181/angular-ui-router-how-to-prevent-access-to-a-state)

Comment: I quess you already populate req.user somehow, so now you can simply response according to req.user.role for example for admin route `if(req.user !== 'admin) return res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');` otherwise response normaly