# In Angularjs, how to block user approaching to some pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-config

I'm using `ui-router` and `$stateProvider` to show views.

This project is for building admin page, and there are three accounts.

My purpose is some pages must be shown to each accounts only.

So, I've used `ng-if` to not show on `nav-bar`, it was successful.

But if typed its url and approached directly, these pages were shown.

Are there any way to make branch in `configs'? or other ways to solve this?

I think this question does not need to post fiddle or plunker,

so I've just put my code of `configs`.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin/login');
$stateProvider
.state('root.for_a', {
    url: '/:brand_id/for_a',
    views: {
        'appContainer@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/for_a.html',
            controller: 'ForACtrl',
        }
    }
})
.state('root.for_b', {
    url: '/:brand_id/for_b',
    views: {
        'appContainer@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/for_b.html',
            controller: 'ForBCtrl',
        }
    }
})
.state('root.for_c', {
    url: '/:brand_id/for_c',
    views: {
        'appContainer@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/for_c.html',
            controller: 'ForCCtrl',
        }
    }
})
```

I'll wait any handsome or pretty programmers can help me. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to secure pages through angularjs. I would never trust client-side code to implement security stuff as client-side scripts can be tampered with easily. Go for a server-side approach if you really want strict security.

Comment: @Verthosa thanks to your comment. I have a problem that I can only build client side..

Comment: Use resolve in ui-router :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518181/angular-ui-router-how-to-prevent-access-to-a-state

Comment: @AnmolMittal thank you for giving this awesome solution link!! +10!!

Comment: ........cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to overcome similar issue was, use 'ng-if' on 'ui-view' tags.

```
 <ui-view ng-if="functionToEvaluatePermissions()"></ui-view>
 <span ng-if="!functionToEvaluatePermissions()"> You shouldn't be here. </span>
```

Comment: Oh, I think this is so attractive solution. I've considered this also, but wanted to know whether there is more specialized solution or not.

Comment: If there is no solution better than this, then I'll choose your answer. :) thank you for your answer.