# AngularJS | Redirect to MainRoute when use does not have permission to see the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angularjs-directive

I am using a multi-tier auth-system, with my AngularJS App(Angular 1.6.4).

Meaning, that a user has multiple permissions. Depending on the permission he has he can see or not the page the permissions apply to.

I have already managed to hide all the necessary HTML Elements regarding that screen depending on the permission level. But now I am having a bit of problem protecting the Route Itself.

Basically, I want the user to redirect to my Landing Page if the permissions he has are not contained in the Array of Permissions provided to him on Log-In.

Here is what I did:

```
  $rootScope.$on("rebalancing", () => {
    if (user.permissions !== Role.ViewConnectors || user.permissions !== 
       Role.ManageConnectors) {
      redirectTo(application.APP)
    }
  });
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Can you please help me. I understand that this action needs to be checked before everything else. So, `rootScope` seemed like a good place to start.

**More Info**
The user is provided by the ReduxStore, that I am passing. The `application.APP` is the home route of the application. And the redirectTo, is a custom utility to `redirectTo(/etc...)`

Comment: Usually one use resolve functions in the route configuration to abort loading of an unauthorized route.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular2+ there are RouteGuards, in AngularJS you can use a similar solution with the premise that you are using uiRouter

In your state add a resolve function that checks if the use has the right permission, return a rejected promise if not

```
    resolve: {
       security: ['$q', function($q, Auth){
           // Checking permission here, you can pass the resource or some other 
           // data is necessary
           if(!Auth.isAllowed()){
              return $q.reject("Not Authorized");
           }
       }]
```

This will avoid controller to load.
To redirect to your landingPage add this listener in you application run function

```
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){

            if(error === "Not Authorized"){
                $state.go("landingPageOrWherever");
            }
        });
```

I've tested it and it's working.

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518181/angular-ui-router-how-to-prevent-access-to-a-state)